# XSL Transformation format number to remove decimal and add leading zeros

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I have a case where I need to format a number `1234.56` to `123456` I can do that no problem, I also need to add pad the front of the number with zeros to account for 12 spaces. I can do that as well. The problem is how do I combine the two process to format the number and add the padding?

My code:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(substring(concat(Payment, $Pad50), 1, 12), "0")"/>
```

I am getting an error of:

> Element type "xsl:value-of" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

Comment: Do you mean to remove the decimal *point?*

Comment: Yes, remove and pad zeros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(Payment * 100, '000000000000')"/>
```

The idea is that you're moving the decimal point over two places for the `Payment` node (multiply it by 100) and then telling `format-number` to zero-pad the number so it's 12 characters long (with leading 0s).  The only potential issue is if `Payment` is sometimes very large and multiplying it by 100 could cause an overflow - but your 12 digit cap would suggest that shouldn't become a problem.

Your original code has a few problems:

1. You were passing the last argument to `format-number` incorrectly - use a `'` instead of `"`, otherwise the processor thinks you're closing the `select` attribute and doesn't know what to do with the `0` and another `"`.
2. `concat` and `substring` are going to return strings - `format-number` expects a number as the first argument.  If you cast the string to `number`, you'll lose all your padded zeroes.
3. You could use a different set of functions - assuming `$Pad50` is a string of twelve zeroes:

   ```
   <xsl:value-of select="substring(translate(concat($Pad50, Payment), '.', ''), string-length(Payment), 12)" />
   ```

But this gets messy.